# Issue with Body Argument for POST request

Tags: r, json, rest, azure-devops, httr

I am attempting to create a new team in our instance of Azure Devops through the Devops REST API.  This is being done through R with the package 'httr' for the POST request and 'jsonlite' for the toJSON function.

I have been utilising the documentation on Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to structure the request correctly but keep getting a 400 error (Bad Request).

I am an administrator for the group so have permissions to create teams and the url is correct as I can return data with a GET request.

For the body argument I am using the following code;

```
    args <- list(name = "my new team")
    body <- toJSON(args, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Printing 'body' to the console returns

```
    {"name":"my new team"}
```

which looks consistent with the JSON request body in the Microsoft documentation.

The code for the POST request is below;

```
    create.task <- POST(paste0("https://dev.azure.com/",org.id,"/_apis/projects/",
                   project.id,"/teams?api-version=5.1"), 
                   encode = "json", 
                   authenticate(username, token, type = "basic"), 
                   body = body,
                   verbose())
```

This will return the following error message rather than creating the new Team in Devops.

```
    "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    <- Cache-Control: no-cache
    <- Pragma: no-cache
    <- Content-Length: 446
    <- Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    <- Expires: -1"
```

Unfortunately, this is not reproduce-able but I wanted to see if there is an obvious error that I am making.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting back any JSON with the 400 to tell you what type of 400 error you're getting? According to the docs you linked to it could be for a few reasons: Invalid team name or description 400 Team already exists 400 Insufficient privileges 400

Comment: The link you have referred to says that the security type is oauth2 but you are trying to authenticate with a username and password. Have a look at this which might help https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-authenticate-using-oauth2-through-r-2/

Comment: Thanks @jcragun, I am an administrator in the devops project and have already created teams so I should have sufficient priveleges.  I figured the team name would be valid because its the same example as the Microsoft page.

Comment: Thanks @Dhiraj, I will try that when I am back in the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hugh Lin for the suggestion to go through Postman. From this I got my authorization token and managed to get my request to work. I then exported the code snippet in cURL and used https://curl.trillworks.com/#r to convert the curl command to R httr.

Another difference to my early approach is that I set the Authorization, Host and Content Type with add_headers, and the api-version in the query.

The code below is what I used;

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `Authorization` = 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=',
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json',
  `Host` = 'dev.azure.com'
)

params = list(
  `api-version` = '5.1'
)

data <- toJSON(list(name = "My New Team"), auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)

res <- httr::POST(url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams',
                  httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), 
                  query = params, 
                  body = data)
```

This successfully created the new team.

```
> status_code(res)
[1] 201
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is necessarily a problem with your Authorization. I tested this rest api in Postman and authenticated with PAT. The result of the test is that the team can be created successfully.

[image]
[image]